# Finding the distribution function

Tags: probability, statistics

> Let $X\in \mathbb R^+$, and $\sqrt X$ is uniformly distributed in range $[1,5]$, find the distribution function and the density function.

*Attempt:*

$\sqrt X \sim U(1,5)\implies X\sim U(1,25)$

$F_X(t)=\text{Pr}(X\leqslant t)=?...$

$F'_X(t)=f(X)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{25-1},\qquad 1\leqslant X \leqslant 25\\
0,\qquad \qquad\text{otherwise }\end{cases}$

Can someone please show me how to approach this?

Comment: If $\sqrt{X}$ is uniformly distributed then $X$ is *not* uniformly distributed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $t \in (1,25)$: $$P(X\le t) = P(\sqrt{X} \le \sqrt{t}) = \frac{\sqrt{t}-1}{5-1} = \frac{\sqrt{t}-1}{4}$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{d}{dt}P(X\le t)= \frac{1}{8\sqrt{t}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Define $\sqrt{X} = Y$, thus
$$
F_X(x) = P(X\le x) = P(\sqrt{X} \le \sqrt{x}) = P(Y \le \sqrt{x}) =\frac{\sqrt{x} - 1}{4},  
$$
hence,
$$
f_X(x) = F'_Y(\sqrt{x}) (\sqrt{x})' = f_Y(\sqrt{x})\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} = \frac{1}{8\sqrt{x}} \, , 
$$
for $x \in [1,25]$.