# Find the distributed function of $X$.

Tags: probability, statistics

For a random variable $X$ it's known that $\sqrt X-2$ is uniform distributed in range $[0,5]$, Find the distributed accumulation function of $X$.

*Attempt:*

$\sqrt X-2\sim U(0,5)$

$F_X(t)=$Pr$(X<t)=\frac{t-0}{5-0}=\frac t 5$

$F_X(t)=\begin{cases}0,&t=0\\
t/5,&0\leqslant t\leqslant 5\\
1,&t>5\end{cases}$

But what should I do with the sqrt and -2?

Comment: Ive never heard of union distribution before. Are you referring to the uniform distribution?

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $\sqrt{X} -2 \sim U[0,5]$, thus $\sqrt{X} \sim U[2,7]$, then just follow [these](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2364845/finding-the-distribution-function) steps.